# pick every first occurrence of the column value over a period of time

Tags: sas

I have data as shown below.

```
MSISDN  DATE    NET_TYPE
11111   01/01/2017  1
11111   02/01/2017  1
11111   03/01/2017  1
11111   04/01/2017  2
11111   05/01/2017  2
11111   06/01/2017  2
11111   07/01/2017  2
11111   08/01/2017  2
11111   09/01/2017  1
11111   10/01/2017  1
11111   11/01/2017  1
11111   12/01/2017  1
11111   13/01/2017  1
11111   14/01/2017  2
11111   15/01/2017  2
11111   16/01/2017  2
```

I am looking for a solution where I create a new variable which helps to pick every first and last occurrence of NET_TYPE over a period of time (date values are not fixed, NET_TYPE can be 1 or 2 for days or months or years). The solution i am looking as below.

```
MSISDN  DATE    NET_TYPE    INDICATOR
11111   01/01/2017  1   1
11111   02/01/2017  1   0
11111   03/01/2017  1   1
11111   04/01/2017  2   1
11111   05/01/2017  2   0
11111   06/01/2017  2   0
11111   07/01/2017  2   0
11111   08/01/2017  2   1
11111   09/01/2017  1   1
11111   10/01/2017  1   0
11111   11/01/2017  1   0
11111   12/01/2017  1   0
11111   13/01/2017  1   1
11111   14/01/2017  2   1
11111   15/01/2017  2   0
11111   16/01/2017  2   1
```

if you can provide the solution is SAS is much helpful.

Code I've already tried that doesn't work in SAS:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE 
         WHEN net_type <> COALESCE(Lag(net_type, 1) 
                                     OVER ( 
                                       partition BY sub_no 
                                       ORDER BY dt), 99) THEN dt 
       END AS starting, 
       CASE 
         WHEN net_type <> COALESCE(Lag(net_type, 1) 
                                     OVER ( 
                                       partition BY sub_no 
                                       ORDER BY dt DESC), 99) THEN dt 
       END AS ending 
FROM   table 
ORDER  BY dt
```

Comment: StackOverflow is designed to help coders with their code. We do not write solutions according to your specification. If you have code you tried so far, we may be able to help.

Comment: I dont need complete solution, A hint would be fine to work around. I tried with first. and last. variable using proc sort but didn't work out. I am  trying like this select *,min(dt) over (partition by net_type),max(dt) over (partition by net_type) from sandbox.santhosh

Comment: select *,
case when net_type <> coalesce(lag(net_type, 1) OVER (partition by sub_no ORDER BY dt),99) then dt end as starting,
case when net_type <> coalesce(lag(net_type, 1) OVER (partition by sub_no ORDER BY dt desc),99) then dt end as ending

from table order by dt 


I have tried but it works only in db but not in sas

Comment: I don't think SAS supports partitioning and windowing in SQL statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SAS this is very simple to do if you know enough about data step by-group processing, and very hard to do if you don't. As you've found, proc sql doesn't support the `partition by` syntax that you're using. Here's a data step solution:

```
data have;
input MSISDN & DATE & ddmmyy10. NET_TYPE;
format DATE ddmmyy10.;
cards;
11111   01/01/2017  1
11111   02/01/2017  1
11111   03/01/2017  1
11111   04/01/2017  2
11111   05/01/2017  2
11111   06/01/2017  2
11111   07/01/2017  2
11111   08/01/2017  2
11111   09/01/2017  1
11111   10/01/2017  1
11111   11/01/2017  1
11111   12/01/2017  1
11111   13/01/2017  1
11111   14/01/2017  2
11111   15/01/2017  2
11111   16/01/2017  2
;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by notsorted MSISDN NET_TYPE;
  INDICATOR = first.NET_TYPE or LAST.NET_TYPE;
  put (_all_) (=);
run;
```

When you have a `by` statement in a data step, it creates temporary `first.x` and `last.x` variables for each variable in your `by` statement by automatically looking ahead at the next row in the input dataset.

Usually a `by` statement requires your dataset to be sorted, but the `notsorted` option overrides this and allows you to identify any rows where a variable changes from one value to another, regardless of the ordering.

Comment: I think either SO or your editor has replaced tabs with spaces in the cards statement and the data isn't being read correctly.  If you replace the multiple spaces it works fine.

Comment: @david25272 - fixed